# Which one is the original thread that created the view?

Tags: android, view, ui-thread, game-loop

I have this code in a class named GameLoop (code similar to the LunarLander sample)

```
while( running ) {
    Canvas canvas = null;
    try {
        canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if( t - old[0] >= frame ) {
            old[0] = t;
            synchronized( mSurfaceHolder ) {
                mGame.update();
                mGame.onDraw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        // Do this in finally so that if an exception is thrown
        // we don't leave the Surface in an inconsistent state
        if( canvas != null ) mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

        }
```

The parent class is GameView (reference mGame).
When `mGame.update()` tries to call his own `announce` method,

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

. . .
    private void announce(int resId) {
        synchronized( mSurfaceHolder ) {
            tv_announcement.setText(getContext().getString(resId));
            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv_announcement, "alpha", 0, 1);
            anim.setDuration(ANNOUNCE_DURATION).start();
        }
    }
. . .
```

I get this exception:

```
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

There are two thread here, **the UI thread**, which runs GameView and owns the SurfaceView, **and GameLoop** which is an extension of Thread and only runs the update-draw loop.

As I understand it, the exception is telling me that only the UI thread can touch the TextView `tv_announcement`.
But isn't `announce` running in the UI thread? What am I missing here?

Here is the logcat of the exception after announce:

```
03-22 07:20:19.096: D/GameView(28250): + update(): state:IDLE, next state:CHOOSE_SIDE
03-22 07:20:19.096: D/GameView(28250): + announce(resId:2131361803)
03-22 07:20:19.096: W/dalvikvm(28250): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3040180)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-192
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:709)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6773)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3306)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3137)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at <package>.GameView.announce(GameView.java:436)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at  <package>.GameView.update(GameView.java:314)
03-22 07:20:19.096: E/AndroidRuntime(28250):    at  <package>.GameView$GameLoop.run(GameView.java:495)
03-22 07:20:19.126: D/GameView(28250): + onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus:true)
03-22 07:20:19.126: D/GameView(28250): - onWindowFocusChanged()
```

Comment: how you create thread.give me code.

Comment: Where do you call `announce` method ? Just make sure you call it from UI thread.

Comment: @sajmon I was probably not very clear. I don't manually create the threads. The UI thread is the Activity thread, the GameLoop is a thread becasue it extends Thread. GameLoop is a private class of GameView created on the GameView constructor.

Comment: @fiddler I put already the code, announce is called from GameView, which is UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

Your error is thrown because for sure you are modifying UI from not UI Thread probably from worker Thread.

If you want to update UI with some information from operation performed in Thread or just from some process performed in Thread you can only use:

- [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
- [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Yes, I tried to use a handler to run the loop and then there was no exception thrown by `announce`. Can you explain a little bit why? Is GameView, in my code, considered a Worker thread? (GameView is just instantiated in the Activity XML layout)

Comment: @ilomambo i need logcat of this "annouce"

Comment: @ilomambo you have same error, you are modyfing UI from worker thread man. you have somewhere created normal Thread(also if you are inherit from Thread) and this class makes action it cause same error.

Comment: thanks, I am using a Handler now and send a message to show or hide the textview.